# Exponential sum $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\exp(-tm^2)$ using partial summation

Tags: calculus, summation, analytic-number-theory

In 'Murty, M. Ram; Murty, V. Kumar, Mean values of derivatives of modular L-series. Ann. of Math. (2) 133 (1991), no. 3, 447–475.', p.456, the author claim the lemma

> $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{m}\exp(-tm^2)=O(\exp(-t))$ $\quad$  if $t \geq 1/2$.

However, I couldn't explain why this holds. The author says that this follows easily by partial summation. How we apply partial summation formula to get this lemma?

Comment: side note: $O$ term is an asymptotic object which makes sense when its argument is large, in this case $t\to \infty$ (not for $t\geq \frac12$).

Comment: @Math-fun that's generally not true, big O can be used to describe asymptotic behaviors around finite limits as well (for example using $e^h = 1 +O(h)$ for a Taylor series). Generally analytic number theorists and other mathematicians use slightly different definitions than computer scientists if that is what you are used to. The $t\geq \frac{1}{2}$ gives a neighborhood where this asymptotic formula is valid (uniform convergence since the asymptotics need to be bounded by constants times functions). Which is necessary because the series does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you very much for the comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a formula here, just write out the first few terms:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-tm^2)}{m} = \exp(-t)+ \frac{\exp(-4t)}{2} + \cdots$$

So we can rephrase our question as under what conditions does the first term uniformly dominate the rest of the summation? Rewrite the sum in the following way:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-tm^2)}{m} = \exp(-t) + \sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{\exp(-tm^2)}{m}$$

$$ \leq \exp(-t) + \sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{\exp(-m)}{m} = \exp(-t) - \log(1-e^{-1}) + 1 = O(\exp(-t))$$

But the inequality step only holds if $tm \geq 1$ for all $m$. The smallest $m$ in the summation is $2$, so it follows that $t\geq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What a clear answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ninad Munshi, but $1$ has a growth faster than $\exp(-t)$ for large $t$s (rather, exp(-t) decays to zero whereas the constant stays intact). The upper bound should have been $\mathcal{O}(1)$ right?

Comment: @user166305 you might be making the same mistake as the user in the comments. The big $O$ notation here is $|f(x)-L| = O(h(x))$ or more commonly seen as $f(x) = L + O(h(x))$